# Can I use LIMIT in SQLite3 together as a bound parameter?

Tags: sqlite

Is a statement like

```
SELECT Name FROM Persons WHERE Name LIKE ?1 LIMIT ?2
```

possible in SQLite3? For `?1` I can bind a parameter after the statement is prepared, using https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html. But is this also possible for `?2`? I could not get it to work and now I fear that I have to create a prepare a separate statement for each value of LIMIT, say 1, 10, 100, 1000, etc.

Comment: No. You have to pass it by concatenating the string: `"... WHERE Name LIKE ? LIMIT " + YourLimit.toString();`

Comment: What is the problem? Some error message?

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi Wrong. The limit clause is an expression, thus a query parameter can be apart of it.

Comment: I do not understand why the question is rated down? I would welcome some feedback about it? In my opinion, it is a valid question and interesting to other people. Maybe I did not explain the problem well enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. It works for ?2 the same way as for ?1.

```
int iReturn = sqlite3_bind_text(pStmt, index, acValue, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

For limit, `index` is 2 and acValue is a string which evaluates to an integer. I recommend setting SQLITE_TRANSIENT so that SQLite makes a copy of acValue. Otherwise one has to ensure that acValue does not go out of scope.